# Permissão e níveis de usuários em PHP e AngularJs (JS)

Tags: php, javascript, angularjs

Estou desenvolvendo um painel administrativo onde possuo alguns usuários e estes devem possuir níveis de permissões diferentes.

Ao mesmo tempo, deve ser algo "dinâmico" para que haja o controle das ações básicas, como: ler, editar, adicionar e remover. E isso segmentado por área.

Por exemplo:

#### Usuários

- Joao - Administrador
- Carlos - Atendente

#### Área

- Notícias:

  - João: Controle total
  - Carlos: Controle total
- Suporte

  - João: Controle total
  - Carlos: Ler, Modificar

---

Esse controle deve ser armazenado no banco de dados (`MySql` & `PHP`) para que haja o controle de permissão também no *backend*. Para atingir esse objetivo, pensei em 2 modos, mas não sei quais as vantagens de usar um ou outro.

### Modelo 1

Criar uma tabela de gerenciamento de permissões, exemplo:

```
id(PK) | id_usuario(int) | area(string) | permissao(string)
1      | 12              | noticia      | tudo
2      | 14              | noticia      | ler
3      | 14              | noticia      | editar
```

Assim, para cada área e cada ação desejada, basta inserir ou remover um novo registro no banco.

#### Modelo 2

Criar apenas mais um campo na tabela dos usuários, e.x. `permissao` e guardar um objeto em JSON para validação futura. Sendo algo assim:

```
permissao: {
    noticia: {
        ler: true,
        editar: true,
        adicionar: true,
        remover: false
    },
    suporte: {
        ler: true,
        editar: false,
        adicionar: false,
        remover: false
    }
}
```

E para inserir no banco, basta usar o `serialize` do PHP.

---

O segundo método me parece mais prático, pois facilita o uso no *frontend* e parece ser melhor gerenciável inclusive para o *backend*.

Porém, como não desenvolvi nada do tipo até então, não sei se estou ignorando algum ponto importante, visto que isso envolve segurança nas informações, pois preciso gerenciar quais usuários controlam determinadas áreas.

Posso ( e provavelmente também será feito) a utilização de um outro campo para permitir o acesso àquela área, e.x. `acesso: true` para permitir que o usuário acesse uma página antes mesmo de verificar se pode editar o conteúdo.

Comment: O método mais seguro e dinâmico é o do banco de dados, depende da complexidade de permissões que você quer setar. 
Uma tabela relacionada ao usuário, ou grupo de usuários me parece um bom método. A solução ideal ficaria algo em torno dos seus 2 métodos, ficaria mais fácil de adicionar novos módulos e novas permissões caso necessário. No sistema que desenvolvi utilizo 3 tabelas, uma de módulos, uma de permissões customizadas, e uma de relação com grupo de usuário, além disso utilizo um accessLevel que é responsável por separar users, admins, devs, e camadas de nível de usuário diferentes.

Comment: Existem ainda, outras implicações quanto à permissão com javascript, chamadas à estruturas de dados de permissão devem ser sempre "síncronas", evitando que a parte "protegida" seja executada em paralelo com a checagem de permissão.

Comment: Esqueci de comentar, que nos meus acessLevel do modelo ACL ainda tenho "anonimo" e "publico", em anonimo são as telas que apenas usuários não logados podem acessar (login, recuperação de senha, etc) e public são telas que não necessitam de autenticação alguma.